# Processing excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell

I have some 40-50 excel files that have useful information in the first 20x25 cells and then junk beyond these cell. What is the easiest way to clean up the junk from all the files in one fell swoop, so that only the first 20x25 cells remain? Can I do this using Powershell on Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest way to do this is a VBA macro in Excel:

```
Sub CleanFiles()
' for each file in a directory
'    open it, delete all cell content around the first 20x25 cells, write it back
' 2015-10-15

    Dim path As String, aFile As String
    Dim arr As Variant

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    path = "D:\TEMP\xls\"          ' must have trailing backslash
    aFile = Dir(path & "*.xls")
    Do While aFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = aFile
        aFile = path & aFile
        Workbooks.Open (aFile)

        ' process file content
        arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Y20")
        Cells.Clear
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Y20") = arr

        ' save and close WB
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True, aFile
        aFile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

First, screen updating and Auto macros are disabled. Then, a specific folder is scanned for '*.xls' files and each file is opened. The contents of the area to be preserved is saved internally, then the whole sheet is cleared and the contents written back to the sheet. When closing the file, it's saved without prompting.

Answer (score -1):

You could do a `Get-Content file.csv | select -First 25 | Export-Csv newfile.csv` if you mean the first 20-25 rows.
You could do a `Get-Content -Header @("a","b","c") file.csv | Select a,b,c | Export-Csv newfile.csv` and so on in that order to select all the way through y, which would be your 25th column.  There might be a better way though.